# convert term to variable in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a list of terms,

```
[g(_G543),g(_G548),g(_G553),g(_G558),g(_G558),g(_G553),g(_G548),g(_G543)]
```

How can I make it to

```
[_G543,_G548,_G553,_G558,_G558,_G553,_G548,_G543]
```

only left the variables.

I was trying

```
replace([],[]).
replace([g(X)|T1],[X|T2]):-
    replace(T1,T2).
```

but it just returned a false, what should I do? Thanks

Comment: @DanielLyons I was trying to make my explanation simple, didn't notice that, corrected.

Comment: @false but it returns a false

Comment: @false I solved the problem, the program is really work, the problem is somewhere else, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list looks like your example

```
[ g(A) , g(B) , g(C) , g(A) ... ]
```

something like this ought to do you:

```
extract_vars( []        , []     ) .  % if the source list is exhausted, we're done
extract_vars( [g(V)|Xs] , [V|Vs] ) :- % otherwise...
  var(V) ,                            % - ensure we've got a var
  ! ,                                 % - eliminate the choice point
  extract_vars( Xs , Vs )             % - recurse down
  .                                   %
extract_vars( [_|Xs] , Vs ) :-        % anything else, we chuck
  extract_vars( Xs , Vs )             %
  .                                   % Easy!
```

You could probably use `findall\3`, too:

```
extract_vars( Xs , Vs ) :-
  findall( V , (member(g(V),Xs),var(V)) , Vs )
  .
```

Comment: Even I solved it, but your answer is more logical, I can learn it from your code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The underscore names eg. _G553 have no real relevance, so there's no need to maintain the exact names ?

In which case, assuming all list items are all g(..), there is no need to recurse through them.. just create a new list with the same length as the input list, but without the 'g' prefix:

```
X=[g(_G543),g(_G548),g(_G553),g(_G558),g(_G558),g(_G553),g(_G548),g(_G543)], length(X, Len), length(Y,Len).

X = [g(_G543), g(_G548), g(_G553), g(_G558), g(_G558), g(_G553), g(_G548), g(_G543)],
Len = 8,
Y = [_G3808, _G3811, _G3814, _G3817, _G3820, _G3823, _G3826, _G3829].
```

Here, length/2 is used to create a list of 'Len' items.

Comment: but some of the variable in the list are same, i need to bind some values to those variables, and make them output as the same order, if I create a new list, the order will gone